Как эту историю коммитов убрать?

Появилось после обновления vs code? Грузится по полчаса и крайне сильно мешает работе.

Ну хоть немного пытайтесь решить проблему сами.. Появилось после обновления? Зайдите и почитайте, что нового. scm.showHistoryGraph

Сам нашёл, заходим в настройки VSCode, далее параметры > система управления версиями, убираем галочку с пункта Show History Graph 
